# Dynamically passing template string with query parameter to the options of signInWithOAuth

Tags: nuxtjs3, supabase

I'm using Nuxt 3 and Supabase (nuxt supabase module) and I'm wondering how can I properly send the query params to the options of signInWithOAuth method
(see below screenshots)

query parameters working but when I try to login I am not redirected (Nothing is happening, but when the string is simple "localhost:3000" it is working)

I really want to know how to do that

[image]

[image]

I tried using template strings and it's not working

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).